Geo nodes set Curve Normal > free, unexpected result
I'm trying to make something in GeometryNodes but the normals are giving me hard time,
First, there is flat straight curve (Group input) with Curve to Mesh and an Arc curve as  profile, and this fine (fig.1)

Next I resample the main curve and push some vertcies outward, so (fig.2) is the result but I wanted all profiles to be oriented in the same direction of the original main curve.

So I used set curve normal and it worked partially because the profile directions is now as desired BUT the profiles at the start and end are now scaled down  (fig.3)

Why the profile arcs at the start and end of the main curve are scaled down?
Did I do something wrong or is it a bug?
I hope someone can help me fix this issue.

I'm experiencing the same problem. Setting custom normals (vector normals only with  x and y axis)  on my curve returns deformed geometry on the z axis

I've opened an issue on the developers platform, You can follow it here
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/122601

The problem is fixed in release 4.3.0 with Issue 122601
